# Python for loops and if statements

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a function which uses a for loop to iterate through a list of integers and return `True` if there are two 2's next to each other on the list, and `False` otherwise. For example, when I call it with `print(has22([1, 2, 2]))`, it should return `True` . I am new to Python so here is what I have so far, I am unsure of what to put after `and` to specify that I want it to check the next iteration to see if it is a `2` as well. Any help is appreciated.

```
    def has22(nums):
    """Checks a list for two 2's"""
    for num in nums:
        if num == 2 and 
        return(True)
    else: return(False)
```

Comment: 1st of all you are missing the third `"` in your docstring.

Comment: You probably want to iterate over indices: `for i in range(len(nums)): num = nums[i]...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built in `any()` to check for two consecutive twos as the following:

```
def has22(nums):
    return True if any(nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2 for i in range(len(nums)-1) else False
```

Alternatively, you can modify your for loop to the following:

```
def has22(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the -1 in `for i in range(len(nums)-1):` is for?

Comment: Because we're using `nums[i+1]` if you just use `len(nums)` it will raise index out of range exception when reaching the last element. Using `len(nums)-1` will loop to the element before last so `i+1` reaches last element only and not further

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find it useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
def has22(nums):
    for count,num in enumerate(nums):
       try:
          if num == 2 and nums[count+1]==2:
             return(True)
       except IndexError: pass
    return(False)
```

Try enumerate.

Comment: Added try and except

Comment: Might want to use a specific `except` like `except IndexError:` instead of `except:`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
def has22(nums):
    """Checks a list for two 2's"""
    gotone = False
    for num in nums:
        if num == 2:
            if gotone:
                return True
            else:
                gotone = True
        else:
            gotone = False
    return(False)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

First, set two variables(one for recording the last num and another for recording the current num) to something that is not 2. Then, loop through all numbers and first set the current number to `num`. Then, compare the last number variable(`last_num`) and the current number variable(`current_num`) to `2`. If both returns True, then, `return True`. Then, set `last_num` to the number. Finally, if nothing was found, `return False`.

```
def has22(nums):
    last_num = -1
    current_num = -1
    for num in nums:
        current_num = num
        if (current_num == 2) and (last_num == 2):
            return True
        last_num = num
    return False
```